# Adding Index changes query result

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection with the following schema:

```js
db.posts.insert({sents:
    [
        {uni:['a','b','c'],bi:[['a','b'],['b','c']]},
        {uni:['x','y','z'],bi:[['x','y'],['y','z']]}
    ]})
```

the following query returns the record inserted above:

```js
> db.posts.find({'sents.bi':{'$elemMatch':{'$in':['a']}}})
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("537595f254bae6dfabddf0c9"), 
     "sents" : [     
         { 
             "uni": [ "a", "b", "c" ],
             "bi": [[ "a", "b" ],  [ "b", "c" ] ] 
         },
         {
             "uni": [ "x", "y", "z" ],  
             "bi": [ [ "x",    "y" ],  [ "y", "z" ] ] 
         } 
     ] 
}
```

However, after I create an index on 'sents.bi':

```js
>db.posts.ensureIndex({'sents.bi':1})
```

the above query stops working:

```js
> db.posts.find({'sents.bi':{'$elemMatch':{'$in':['a']}}}).count()
0
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, I just don't know what it is that I'm doing wrong :)

Thank you,

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: With or without index, the query above doesn't give me anything anyway.

Comment: @yaoxing That is because you are using a 2.6 version or greater. The full reason is commented on your answer.

Comment: FYI. I just created [SERVER-13963](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13963) to cover this.

Answer (score 1):

As the query you listed above doesn't give me anything with or without an index. I'm thinking do you possibly mean:

```
db.posts.find({'sents.bi':{'$elemMatch': {$elemMatch: {$in: ['a']}}}})
```

Note you got an array in an array. You'll have to do the $elemMatch twice.

Comment: This is right. The interesting thing is the original stated query works in versions prior to 2.6. Up until an index is created of course. The other point there is the index is the reason for the failure because MongoDB cannot use an embedded array as an index element. But the query form as shown here will not select that index, so it works. But you cannot index a field like this for a performance gain.

Comment: yes I'm using 2.6. I also tried $hint to force using the index. Although it becomes "BtreeCursor", it still scanned other objects in this collection which doesn't even have a "sents" property. Seems the index still doesn't take effect.

Comment: All covered in the JIRA issue referenced above.